# Invoking a functions based on string name in java

Tags: string, methods, invoke

I need a logic to replace the following code.

```
 void invokeMethod(String action){
    if ("echo".equals(action)) {
         //call echo
         echo();
    } 
    else if ("dump".equals(action)) {
         // call dump
         dump();
    }
    ... goes on
}
```

switch case with string parameter won't work in java 1.6.
Can I do it a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a java hashmap with action as key and random integer as value. Whenever perticular action is asked to invoke, fetch the integer from the hashmap and use switch case now (In above problem, string comparison was very operation, replaced the same with integers).